# Compare DateTime and date as string

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have value of DateTime and date as string. String date can be in unknown format (1 of 2 in my case : `"MMM dd yyyy"` or `"dd MMM"` ). I need to check if dates are eaqual.

Is there any other solution than trying to parse string date with first and second formats and if one return DateTime than compare with DateTime Type?

Comment: "trying to parse string date with first and second formats and if one return DateTime than compare with DateTime Type" you do not need to Parse two times, you only need to add the two formats to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method. There are several overloads of the function.

One of the overloads is [`ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified array of formats,
>   culture-specific format information, and style. The format of the
>   string representation must match at least one of the specified formats
>   exactly or an exception is thrown.

```
string[] formats= {"MMM dd yyyy", "dd MMM"};

var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                   formats, 
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                   DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Keep in mind that, the format of the string representation must match at least one of the specified formats exactly or an exception is thrown. If you didn't want to use `try/catch` block explicitly, then your best choice will be [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This will return `true` if the parameter was converted successfully; otherwise, `false`.

```
DateTime dateValue;

Nullable<DateTime> result = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
          DateTimeStyles.None, 
          out dateValue)) ? 
    dateValue :
    (DateTime?)null;
```

Comment: @Jamiec I didn't understand the question. I have changed the formats to match the ones in the question. But, they werw different anyways in the previous one.

Comment: You did a pretty good job of answering it then ;). BTW, you probably want to pass `InvariantCulture` rather than `en-US`

Comment: Would it not be better to use TryParseExact and parse out a nullable DateTime? That way an exception isn't thrown if the date doesn't meet your formats (OP said format could be unknown) and you can check against null.

Comment: @sr28 Yes, I agree with you. Will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: Your amendment for TryParseExact won't work. If it fails to convert it can't return null so will return the minimum value. You need to make dateValue nullable and then check against whether it's null or not.